# tween or morph many elements based on css class selector using mootools?

Tags: mootools

how do i tween/morph the height of many elements at once selected by css class selector using mootools?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basics of MooTools:

```
$$('div').each(function(el, index){
    el.morph({
        height: 100 * index
    });
});​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbrNq/